# angularjs: download REST API response as CSV file

Tags: angularjs

I have a REST API whose response json (array of objects).

I would like to provide a button in my view like "Download results to CSV"  and 
and when user clicks on the link csv file should be downloaded with comma separated values.

What is best way to achieve this in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle `(not the author)`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motowilliams/7rL2C/)

You can either implement that on your client side, or alternatively on your server side with a new API call to get the CSV file directly.

Comment: could? you provide an example in angularjs

Comment: The CSV parsing is just plain Javascript, you should be able to use that method on your object returned by the API call.